# Determine brightness of bulbs in a sImple parallel circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

I have a parallel/series circuit given in the following link:

[image]

The question, listed here:

> Suppose that you were to unscrew light bulb $L3$. what would happen to the other bulbs?
>
> A. $L3$, $L4$, $L5$ will get brighter, $L2$ will dim
>
> B. $L4$, $L5$ will brighten, while $L1$ will dim.
>
> C. All bulbs will go out.
>
> D. $L4$, $L5$ will dim, $L2$, $L1$ will brighten.
>
> E. All of the other light bulbs will dim.

I thought that the total current would decrease due to the increase in resistance of the circuit. Thus, the power $I^2 R$ dissipated by each light will decrease due to the drop in current, and each bulb would dim.

However, answer D is the correct answer choice. It states that light bulbs $L1$ and $L2$ will brighten, whereas $L4$ and $L5$ will dim. This makes some sense to me, however I would like to get a further understanding of the concepts, if possible.

Comment: I understand that you can't put an image of the circuit diagram inline yet, but you should consider transcribing the question instead of making people read it from the image.  This will increase the chances that people will read it and be able to help you.

Comment: @tmwilson26 , Thank you for the suggestion, I have changed the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the bulb glows brighter?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154925/why-the-bulb-glows-brighter)

Comment: While not an obvious duplicate, the answers explain the circumstances in which parallel/series bulbs would brighten/dim.

Answer (score 1):

First - simplify the circuit. You have $L_4$ and $L_5$ in series (on opposite sides of the battery but that doesn't matter for calculating the current through them) and $L_1$ and $L_2$ in series. The simplified circuit looks like this:

[image]

Now we consider what happens to the current in $R_1$ if we remove $R_2$: clearly, the total current through the circuit has to flow through $R_1$ and since the total circuit resistance is larger, the circuit current is smaller and so the current through $R_1$ is smaller.

Now that we know the current through $R_1$ is smaller, the voltage drop across $R_1$ must be smaller as well. This means that there is a greater voltage across $R_3$.

These things should allow you to confirm that D is indeed the right answer - and that it doesn't matter what the relative resistances are.

As an aside, we know that the actual resistance of a light bulb is a strong function of temperature - so as a bulb gets brighter, its resistance also goes up. But that is never enough to change the direction of this conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the total resistance increases since $L3$ is removed, therefore the total current also decreases.  However, at the point where the current splits for ($L1$,$L2$) and $L3$, the **sum** of the current between the two legs of the circuit must equal the total current.  When $L3$ is disconnected, ($L1$,$L2$) no longer have to share the total current and gets the total current of the circuit running through them.  Although the total current decreases, it is by an amount less through ($L1$,$L2$) than if it is sharing the current with $L3$.

So, the point is, you need to calculate the current through each bulb in both situations individually and then compare.  Each bulb experiences different changes in current that is not necessarily the change in the total current.

EDIT: Additional details.

To prove this we can do the following:

We'll let the respective resistance for each bulb $L_i$ be $R_i$.  The equivalent resistance of the parallel section of the circuit is:

$$R_{par} = \left(\frac{1}{R_3} + \frac{1}{R_1+R_2}\right)^{-1} = \frac{(R_1+R_2)R_3}{R_1+R_2+R_3}$$

So, the total resistance that the battery sees is:

$$R_{tot} = R_4 + R_5 + R_{par}$$

Meaning the total current is:

$$I_{tot} = \frac{V}{R_{tot}}$$

Lets call the current that $R_1$ and $R_2$ see $I_{1,2}$ and the current that $R_3$ sees $I_3$.  The node where the current splits is a current divider, and we can write the current through each leg of the circuit as:

$$I_{1,2} = \frac{R_3}{R_1+R_2+R_3}I_{tot}$$

and

$$I_3 = \frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1+R_2+R_3}I_{tot}$$

Note that as $R_3$ increases, $I_{1,2}\rightarrow I_{tot}$, and $I_3\rightarrow 0$

Also note that $I_{tot}$ is decreasing as well as $R_3$ increases.

I'll try to do a bit more later if I can.  Maybe Floris' answer below is a simpler way to look at it.

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought, the net increase in current of the two bulbs is positive. Is there any way to prove/show this true? Would it be possible for the resistance to be so high such that the current through the bulbs would be greater before removing L3, rather than after? Would it depend on the resistance of each bulb?

Comment: Yes, you could derive an expression for the current through each bulb for arbitrary values of each of the bulb resistances.  My gut feeling tells me that the current will always increase through L1 and L2 if you remove L3 just because it will take less current from the total current.  As the resistance of L3 increases to large values, the current through L1 and L2 approaches that of the total current of the circuit.  If I have time tonight I'll edit my answer with some equations for you.