# Conceptual Doubt Regarding Electric Circuits

Tags: electricity

There are a few questions which have always bugged me. Unfortunately, due to time constraints, I end up memorizing an example, hoping to imitate that knowledge in an exam question. Consider the following situation, given a circuit with a battery (negligible internal resistance) and a light bulb that is glowing. Let $V$ denote the emf and let $I$ denote the current flowing in the circuit.

1) By increasing which variable will we be able to increase the Brightness of the Bulb?

2) This is a more specific question: Suppose the Bulb is glowing normally (given the initial conditions [$V,I$]) then if consider this new circuit (illustrated below). $R$ is a resistor with Resistance equal to $R$. The question is: What will be the resulting emf?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To increase the glow of bulb you need more energy. So increase the emf. However mind that the value of current should not exceed the current rating value of the bulb.
You should be careful not to use emf inappropriately. Emf is the energy given by the electric source (here the battery) to the charges per unit charge. Otherwise it's the energy given per unit charge. But that's not equal to p.d. Potential difference between two terminals is the work done in moving a unit charge from one terminal to the other. It may not be equal to the emf. In the second picture the emf is the same. But the p.d. across the bulb is now different as you introduced a resistor there. There occurs a lose in energy of the electrons. hence, by definition, now you can't use the term emf.